# How do I get the keyCode currently assigned to the Input Manager?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to look up the keyCode I want from the Input Manager (Edit -> Project Settings -> Input), where I've set up axes, for example "Console" => "^", using the `Name` of the axis.

But I can't find where the axes are exposed, let alone their properties.
Research yields nothing, documentation focuses on setting up axes in the Inspector, or getting the axes' *values*.

**TL;DR**

What I need is to get the resulting KeyCode of an Input's currently assigned positive key, by axis Name.

Something like `keyCode myKey = Input.getAxesByName("NameOfAxis")[0].positiveKey;` ...but that one obviously doesn't exist.

I could also iterate through the axes, writing that function myself (within a `for`loop: `if(Input.Axes[i].Name == NameOfAxis) return Input.Axes[i].keyCode;` ... if only I knew how to get to them.

Can somebody point me to where the inputs/axes are exposed?

Comment: Currently building my own input manager -.- ...really, it would've been so easy, why haven't they included something as simple as that? Well, maybe they have and I just haven't found it

Comment: What you are looking for does not exist. Are you going to use this for Editor or Build?

Comment: @Programmer Ah, shame... Looking to implement it for build. Crafting my own input manager right now. Luckily, that seems to be quite easy even without looking up techniques on it. Finally I can add my own methods

Comment: It could be a possible thing in the Editor with the help of reflection. Since you mentioned build, it is very unlikely you can do it. If you really want this added to Unity, you can always suggest feature on Unity website. and yah, the way you mentioned is a work around and should do it.

Comment: As @Programmer already described, it's not implemented in Unity yet. What I did and would do again is, grab a free stuff from here: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=input&manager&price:0 and take the 'keycode to display name' table implemented there (IMHO the best is static readonly dictionary for these pairs), add my own methods to set/retrieve keys, implement my own key config window and this is it.

Comment: @Mark Thanks... is there a reason why I should use a table (I assume some `Dictionary` type)? I'm currently using KeyCode.toString() and an Enum Parse from the resulting string in the reverse. Seems to work writing to my persistent .ini file and reading from it

Comment: Yup, there is. Oh well. There could be. You might want to display a different name instead of the 'technical name' (e.g. "Joy" only as of left/right/up/down/etc control name), or the actual name is too long for your display field, or for localization issues... If none of these -or anything else- will apply in your case, it's not a mandatory thing of course

Comment: FYI: I haven't had time to test it yet, but it seems this is part of the as yet experimental next gen input manager: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/12/developing-the-new-input-system-together-with-you/

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out and blogged the solutions [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/unity3d-get-inspector-property-values-programatically/).

```
var inputManager = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset")[0];  
SerializedObject obj = new SerializedObject(inputManager);
SerializedProperty axisArray = obj.FindProperty("m_Axes");
if (axisArray.arraySize == 0)
    Debug.Log("No Axes");

for( int i = 0; i < axisArray.arraySize; ++i )
{
    var axis = axisArray.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
    var name = axis.displayName;      //axis.displayName  "Horizontal"  string
    axis.Next (true);   //axis.displayName      "Name"  string
    axis.Next (false);      //axis.displayName  "Descriptive Name"  string
    axis.Next (false);      //axis.displayName  "Descriptive Negative Name" string
    axis.Next (false);      //axis.displayName  "Negative Button"   string
    axis.Next (false);      //axis.displayName  "Positive Button"   string
    var value = axis.stringValue;  //"right"

    Debug.Log(name + " | " + value);
}
```

Below snapshots might be helpful to understand how this works.
[image]
[image]

[SerializedProperty.Next](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.Next.html), programmatically traverses the properties, and can help get the string representation of the keyCode.

Comment: I left a comment about this under OP's question. I said **"It could be a possible thing in the Editor with the help of reflection. Since you mentioned build, it is very unlikely you can do it"**. Sadly, OP wants to do this in a build and this won;t work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Even if it's not applicable in Build, it's useful and gives us insight into both the Editor mechanisms and the internal Input handling.

I since found out that this widely demanded feature was incorporated into the as yet experimental in development version of the next generation input manager: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/12/developing-the-new-input-system-together-with-you/